# Python 3 not recognizing boolean condition

Tags: python

I am migrating python2 code to python3 and have learned there are some minor differences in the call parameter handling that is stricter in python3. This same code used to determine if a feature was enabled by the conditional boolean `floatclock_enabled`. After adding several log print lines in the code, I was able to confirm that the first line of code was always resolving to `True`, even when I logged the string before and after the test. The print results were both `False`, yet it ran `True` in the flow.

```
    if ss.floatclock_enabled:
```

It looks like a bug to me and the way I solved it was the following line.

```
    if str(ss.floatclock_enabled) == 'True':
```

Any suggestions where this anomaly might be caused? My other `_enabled` variables work normally, so far.

Comment: Could you share the code that populates this attribute? your if statement should work in python3

Comment: Did you try using ```True``` without quotation marks?

Comment: Assuming `floatclock_enabled` is set to to the bool value `True`, this code will evaluate correctly, no matter which version of Python you are using.

Comment: Maybe it's not a boolean. Did you print it print(ss.floatclock_enabled)?

Comment: A [mcve] would help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not next Python, check this https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes for `thread` and `threadName` to include this into your logs to be sure that they are from the same thread. Also print `floatclock_enabled` via `repr`, if it has string value `"False"` it would be printed as `False`, but evaluates to boolean `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the quick responses. After further analysis, I found in my long list of `configparser` load items I had used `config.get` instead of `config.getboolean`. Since my initial load used the boolean get, I assumed it wouldn't matter later until I scrutinized my code. Again, I appreciate the quick response and suggestions. I will be scrutinizing more before the next time I post!